# Allow main domain and disallow subfolders access via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I try the following in my .htaccess file to disallow access to several subdirectories without using http-auth (e.g. admin and vpu folder, in real there are more). Unfortunately it works on my dev server but not on my live server - on the live server the access to admin, etc. is not restricted. I would like to avoid placing .htaccess folders in the subdirectories; at least there is one I can't write to. 
Did I miss something?

```
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^(www\.)?my-domain\.com$ allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^(admin|vpu)$ !allowed
AuthUserFile "/var/www/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile "/var/www/.htgroup"

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter password"
require group admins

Order allow,deny
allow from env=allowed
Satisfy any
```

Thank you for a hint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how it is working on localhost as `SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI` starts matching with a leading slash like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/(admin|vpu)$ !allowed
```

Try this full code:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase HOST ^(www\.)?my-domain\.com$ allowed
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/(admin|vpu)$ !allowed

AuthUserFile "/var/www/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile "/var/www/.htgroup"

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter password"
require group admins

Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
allow from env=allowed
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's still not working :(

Comment: not working is never enough for error reporting. Clarify what error you're getting and what URL did you enter in browser